# Sigma ring generated by the class of compact subsets of X

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

In P Halmos measure theory book it written

A Sigma ring **S** generated by **C**, the class of compact subsets of X where X is locally compact Hausdorff Space. Then **S** has open set and sets of **S** is called Borel Sets.

I am very confused. How a sigma ring generated by the class of compact set has open set.

*P Halmos Measure theory book:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the linked excerpt, it appears you may be misinterpreting Halmos here.  He is not claiming that $\mathbf S$ contains ***every*** open set.  He is specifically defining $\mathbf U$ to be the class of open sets contained in $\mathbf S$, so clearly he anticipates not every open set necessarily belongs to $\mathbf S$.

Now, certainly there are ***some*** open sets in $\mathbf{S}$, and in fact you can conclude that every relatively compact open set is in $\mathbf{S}$, since such a set's boundary and closure lie in $\mathbf{S}$.

If the claim were that ***all*** open sets are in $\mathbf S$, then this would indeed be false without additional countability assumptions.  However, that does not appear to be what Halmos is claiming.

---

##### Remark

To see that in general, we can't expect $\mathbf S$ to contain all open sets, let $\omega_1$ be the first uncountable ordinal (aka, the set of countable ordinals), equipped with the order topology.  Then $\omega_1$ is locally compact Hausdorff, (for each $\alpha\in \omega_1$, $[0,\alpha]$ is a compact neighborhood), yet compact subsets of $\omega_1$ must be bounded, since if $A\subseteq \omega_1$ is unbounded, then the open cover $\{[0,\alpha]\mid \alpha\in A\}$ has no finite subcover.

Therefore each compact set is countable, and so every member of $\mathbf S$ is countable.  In particular, $\mathbf S$ cannot contain any unbounded open set, such as $\omega_1$ itself, for example.